# Insert table in XML-view

Tags: sapui5

I created a table in my controller-function `onRoutePatternMatched`.
Now I want to bring this table to the view.
This should be done with `oTable.placeAt("sample1");`

What is the right code to insert it on a specific place in my xml-view?

Home.view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<mvc:View controllerName="ztest.controller.VarConf" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <Page>
              <content id="sample1"></content>
        <content id="sample2">
            <Label text="{varConfDet>/chassisnr}" />

        </content>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Error:
`sap-ui-core.js:152 Uncaught Error: DOM element with ID 'sample1' not found in page, but application tries to insert content.`

Comment: Why not defining the table inside the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. put an id on on the page and not on its content aggregation(s): `<Page id="myPge">`
2. in Controller call `this.getView().byId("myPage").addContent(oTable);`

Because content os the default aggregation of the sap.m.Page you could also only call `this.getView().byId("myPage").add(oTable);`. Also be aware that you might to remove previously added content... Of course, you could also use different panels etc. with different ids and place the table somewhere in there...